# JSF Primefaces don't run validator on blur event

Tags: java, validation, jsf, primefaces

**Situation**:
I have a p:dataTable containing p:inputText. All of those inputTexts are validated by a self written validator. This validator opens a p:dialog which displays the error message in a p:messages component and a p:commandButton to close the dialog. The validator is called when text is input into the inputText and when the inputText loses its focus(blur-event).

*My Dialog:*

```
<p:dialog id="dlgMessageDialog" dynamic="false" style="z-index: 100"
    closable="false" widgetVar="wigVarDlgMessageDialog" modal="true"
    appendTo="@(body)">
        <p:messages id="messageDialogMessages" autoUpdate="true"
            for="#{messageDialogBean.messageClientId}" closable="false"
            escape="false" showDetail="true" showIcon="true" showSummary="true"></p:messages>
        <p:spacer height="20px"></p:spacer>

        <p:commandButton id="closeMessageDialogBtn" value="#{msg.btnOk}"
            oncomplete="PF('wigVarDlgMessageDialog').hide()"></p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
```

*My Dialog Bean:*

```
@Named("messageDialogBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MessageDialogBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4258641757966332708L;

private FacesMessage lastMessage;
private final String messageClientId = "messageDialogMessageId";

public MessageDialogBean() {
}

public void showInfo(final String pSummary, final String pDetail) {

    this.lastMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, pSummary, pDetail);
    showCurrentMessage();

}

public void showError(final String pSummary, final String pDetail) {

    this.lastMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, pSummary, pDetail);
    showCurrentMessage();

}

public void showFatal(final String pSummary, final String pDetail) {

    this.lastMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, pSummary, pDetail);
    showCurrentMessage();

}

public void showWarn(final String pSummary, final String pDetail) {

    this.lastMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, pSummary, pDetail);
    showCurrentMessage();

}

public void showMessage(final FacesMessage pMessage) {

    this.lastMessage = pMessage;
    showCurrentMessage();

}

public FacesMessage getLastMessage() {
    return this.lastMessage;
}

public String getMessageClientId() {
    return this.messageClientId;
}

private void showCurrentMessage() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(this.messageClientId, this.lastMessage);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('wigVarDlgMessageDialog').show()");
}

}
```

*My validator:*

```
@FacesValidator("custom.ValueRequiredValidator")
public class ValueRequiredValidator implements Validator, ClientValidator {

@Inject
private MessageDialogBean messageDialogBean;

public ValueRequiredValidator() {
    if (this.messageDialogBean == null) {
        this.messageDialogBean = new MessageDialogBean();
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getMetadata() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getValidatorId() {
    return "custom.ValueRequiredValidator";
}

@Override
public void validate(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()) {
        this.messageDialogBean.showError("Validierung", "Es sind nicht alle notwendigen Werte vorhanden");

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Nicht alle benötigten Werte vorhanden",
                "Es sind nicht in allen benötigten Feldern Werte eingetragen");
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }
}

}
```

*My Textfield in the p:dataTable*

```
<p:inputText id="someId" value="#{myBean.someValue}" style="width:100%">
<f:validator validatorId="custom.ValueRequiredValidator" />
</p:inputText>
```

**Problem**:
If an invalid value is put into the inputText, the validator opens the dialog. Once you close the dialog useing the button, the inputText loses its focus and fires the blur-event. This causes the validator to run again and open the dialog a second time.

**Question**:
How can i avoid my validator from running when the blur-event is fired by my inputText?

Comment: validation of  `<p:inputText>` should be by default triggered only when form is submitted. Is there any place in your code which define to validate this field on blur event ? something like `<p:ajax update='formId' event="blur">`. Have you got something like this in your code ?

Comment: @ArturSkrzydło thanks for the hint. i ve actually found a ajax registered for the event "keyup" which causes this behaviour. It does updates but the weird thing is it only updates a button, a dropdown and the p:growl element. The inputtext isnt contained in any of them. So it shouldn't be updated, right?

Comment: could you provide some jsf code of this ?  where this event is registered ?

Comment: @ArturSkrzydło inside the inputText. looks basically like that: <p:inputText ...> <p:ajax event="keyup" update="growl" /></inputText>. I managed to fix the problem with your help. Thanks